# model plugin doesn't receive data from a subscribed topic

Tags: gazebo-model, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey,

I have a problem and I think it comes from a stupid mistake, but I am not able to find it.

I have a world and a model plugin and data has to be exchanged. So I use the message system to send and receive messages. It works fine, both plugins are loaded and the model plugin sends a message to the world plugin. The data is received and the world plugin sends some data back. But the callback-function of the model plugin is never called.

Can you take a quick look and tell me what I did wrong?
Here is the code [code](http://pastebin.com/A6qdNnz3)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3736/model-plugin-doesn%27t-receive-data-from-a-subscribed-topic/) by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 67 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe this is related to a problem with the Gazebo transport system. In the world pulgin message callback, you're creating a publisher then sending a message and then immediately deleting the node and publisher. The result is that the message doesn't have a chance to be sent.

The workaround is to make the node and publisher a member of the World Plugin. You should only have at most one node per class anyway.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/269/chris/) on 2013-07-24**:
Thank you, that solves my problem!